# AWS-SDK Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server

Tags: amazon-web-services, metadata, credentials, amazon-iam

Recently my webserver stopped responding due to:

> Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server

Searching for this error I found a suggestion to use `CredentialProvider` to cache credentials locally so the server doesn't have to hit metadata server for each request. But most of them were in the context of credentials in ENV variable or in file

I want to ask if that is also applicable for IAM role and if so does this code make sense?

```
        $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
                         'region' => S3_REGION,
                         'version' => '2006-03-01',
                         'credentials' => CredentialProvider::memoize(CredentialProvider::defaultProvider())
         ));
        try {
            $response = $s3->putObject($option);
        } catch ( Exception $e ) {
            error_log(' couldn\'t set S3 cache for bucket: ' . $option['Bucket'] . ' ' . $e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
```

So my question is Should I use CredentialProvider in case of IAM roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code makes sense and will be an improvement.

Amazon will throttle requests going to `169.254.169.254`. This is most likely the source of your error message. I don't remember what the limit is, but it is recommended to cache the instance credentials. The `memoize()` function does that for you.

[EDIT]

Amazon's comment on throttling. No specific numbers mentioned.

We throttle queries to the instance metadata service on a per-instance basis, and we place limits on the number of simultaneous connections from an instance to the instance metadata service.

[Instance Metadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html)